# Copy data between excel spreadsheets with a given value as a parameter

Tags: excel, vba

Say I have two spreadsheets.

One of the spreadsheets has a table like this:

```
  **Sheet 1**
  A        B        C        D
1 Name     Age      Rank     Number

2 George   22       Master   12

3 Paul     21       Acolyte  22

4 Jimmy    32       Horse    33
 
5 Agnor    12       Cheetah  90
```

The other spreadsheet looks like this:

```
  **Sheet 2**
  A        B        C        D
1 Name     Age      Rank     Number

2 George   

3 Paul     21                22

4 Agnor
```

I want to copy Ages from sheet 1 to sheet 2. So I would copy George, Paul, and Agnor's age, and ignore Jimmy. Which function should I use to copy data based on an existing value?

Is there something like:

```
foreach VAL in Sheet1
if(Sheet1.Name.EqualsIgnoreCase(Sheet2.Name))
{
    Sheet2.Age = Sheet1.Age;
}
```

I looked this up, and a lot of people are saying to use VLookup, but I can't figure out how that would apply.

**EDIT**

I found a similar resolved question (No idea HOW I missed it) here: [Compare and copy data between worksheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692345/help-need-pls-excel-macro-compare-and-copy-between-worksheets)

However, I'm still a little shaky on how to implement this (I'm using Excel 2007).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vlookup would be the easiest way to go.
I will use cell B2 in sheet2 as the reference to try to explain the function
`=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$D$5,2,FALSE)`
The first parameter is the data you are using for a lookup - you may want to change that to `$A2` if you copy the formula around the sheet
The second parameter is where the data is that excel needs to find the value you referenced in the first parameter - use dollar signs. The data doesn't tend to move
The third parameter tells excel what info to return - the 2 means give me the 2nd piece of data
The last parameter tells excel if it can use a close match (`FALSE` for an exact match)

Now to follow Excel and see what it returns.....

First, it looks for `George` in the data (it knows it has to be an exact match from the fourth parameter)
Next, it finds the row `George -- 22 -- Master -- 12` and gives the function the second value (`22` in this case)

Comment: So if I have say 5000 rows in sheet 1, and I only have 2000 matching parameters in sheet 2 (say I only have 2000 matching names, both in column A of their respective sheets)... will this function parse through the entire set of data in sheet 1? (As in, if I copy this to every cell in Sheet 2, row B, will this run a comparison for each value of sheet 2, row B against all values of sheet 1, row A, or is there additional logic I would need to add to this? Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: yes. it will only search for the data you want - if the data is missing (e.g. searching for **Ringo** on your example data) excel will return #N/A. use `iferror` around the function if that's a concern