# excel: replace auto data value for Similar value

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-formula

i have two `excel` files with this data:

File1:

```
Name --------------  Code
John                 12345
Dave                 54321
Maria                98765
Cole                 68596

and .... (1000 name and code)
```

File2:(with code value of file1)

```
Code ------------     address
12345               test address
54321               test address
98765               test address
68596               test address

and .... (1000 name and address)
```

now i need to create one file for show `code / name / address`. how to generate this? how to `excel/(or any method)` replace auto data value for Similar codes. i need to this file :

```
code------------------    name--------------   address
12345                     John                test address
54321                     Dave                test address
98765                     Maria               test address
68596                     Cole                test address
```

`NOTE: code similar in two file.`

Comment: Try looking into vlookup

Comment: Index/Match to get name from File1, Vlookup to get address from file 2

Comment: im very newbie in excel. can u tell me how to work Vlookup with A more detailed description. Thanks

Comment: @user2715503 Try reading the documentation on msdn. It's well detailed and contains some good examples.

Comment: @Jerry: i read docs, But my problem is not solved.

Comment: You should then understand how `VLOOKUP` works and how you can use it here. Try using it, even if it doesn't turn out like you were expecting, then post your attempted formula(s) here by editing your question.

Comment: can u tell me basic formula for my question example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [which function should I use to copy data between excel spreadsheets with a given value as a parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801885/which-function-should-i-use-to-copy-data-between-excel-spreadsheets-with-a-given)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a professional user of Office Products but:

in File 1, let's say if Name is in Column A, and Code in Column B, type this in cell C2:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,'[File2name.xls]Sheet1'!A:B,2,0)'
```

NOTE: `change File2name to the respective file name, and Sheet1 to the worksheet's name if necessary`

and copy the formula down. once done, copy column C, right click column C, and click Paste Special, choose Values and click OK.
and once that's done, rearrange the columns as needed.