# Match a Date between 2 Worksheets then Copy and Paste Specific Data

Tags: excel, find, copy-paste, worksheet-function, vba

- I have 2 work sheets.
- In Sh1 I enter a date in Cell 'R2'.
- The macro
  should then search Sh2 column 'C' for a match.
- When a match is found
  it will copy from 2 cells below my match & 74 cells down then
  PasteSpecial xlPasteValues in Sh1 Cell 'R3'.

The Below example does something similar but not the desired result.

```
Option Explicit 
Sub FindStr() 

Dim rFndCell As Range 
Dim strData As String 
Dim stFnd As String 
Dim fCol As Integer 
Dim sh As Worksheet 
Dim ws As Worksheet 

Set ws = Sheets("CTN ORIGINAL") 
Set sh = Sheets("Ctn Daily - (enter data here)") 
stFnd = ws.Range("R2").Value 

With sh 
    Set rFndCell = .Range("C:C").Find(stFnd, LookIn:=xlValues) 
    If Not rFndCell Is Nothing Then 
        fCol = rFndCell.Column 
        ws.Range("B3:B33").Copy
        sh.Cells(6, fCol).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Else 'Can't find the item
        MsgBox "No Find" 
    End If 
End With 

End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare and copy data between worksheets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692345/compare-and-copy-data-between-worksheets)

Comment: not clear this part **"it will copy from 2 cells below my match & 74 cells down"**. can you explain more?

Comment: for example the match in sheet 2 is found at C50 I want all cells from C52:C156 to be copied and pasted (values only) in R3 of Sheet 1. The location of the match will always change so cant be a static location in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I got one for you, if it is not working let me know. I already tested it and it perfectly work for me.

```
Option Explicit

Sub findAndCopy()

    Dim foundCell As Range
    Dim strFind As String
    Dim fRow, fCol As Integer
    Dim sh1, sh2 As Worksheet

    'Set sheets
    Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    'Get find string
    strFind = sh1.Range("R2").Value

    'Find string in column C of Sheet2
    Set foundCell = sh2.Range("C:G").Find(strFind, LookIn:=xlValues)

    'If match cell is found
    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then

        'Get the row and column
        fRow = foundCell.Row
        fCol = foundCell.Column

        'copy data from Sheet2 (from 2 cell below & 74 cells down)
        sh2.Range(Cells(fRow + 2, fCol).Address & ":" & Cells(fRow + 76, fCol).Address).Copy

        'paste in range R3 of Sheet1
        sh1.Range("R3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        'Clear cache
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'If not found, show message.
    Else

        Call MsgBox("Not found the match cell!", vbExclamation, "Finding String")

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Nicolas. For standard numbers this work perfectly, however i need it to find dates, so far it is unsuccessful.

Comment: I tested with Date, It work for me. What is your input data? Show me. One thing is that If you want to work with date, your **R2 cell from Sheet1** must be **Date** format and **all cells from C column of Sheet2** also must be **Date** format. After that, it will work. If not, not sure to work.

Comment: Both Cells are in the exact same date format 9/02/2015. Cells below the match are in number format.

Comment: Can you post your input data? So, I can think more.

Comment: Should I be using something like this? strdate = Format(strdate, "Short Date")

Comment: Not need.! I also test according to above comment, "cells below the match are in number format". It also work for me. I don't know what is wrong in your input data.

Comment: okay i found out how to make it work but its going to be a pain in the ass. all my dats are in this format *14/01/15

Comment: by changing it to a format without the astrix * it can now work for some reason

Comment: You know one thing that it does not matter in date format, if two cell's format are date format, it will work. I also tested in every way what I though. But no error found for me. If you are OK or not, let me know.

Comment: can you please post the above code but make it search from columns C to G in sheet 2 instead of just column C? Thanks